# $x\in a\cap b \implies x\in c$ and $y\in b\cap c \implies y\in a$ show that $a\cap b = b\cap c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

While looking at a proof of euclidean gcd algorithm, it seems they're using below fact as obvious but I feel stuck :

Given.
$x\in a\cap b \implies x\in c$
and
$y\in b\cap c \implies y\in a$
show that $a\cap b = b\cap c$

---

Using venn diagrams it is easy to see they're the same. I'm looking for other ways to better understand this so that my head begins to accept this as obvious... Any help?

Answer (score 1):

($\rightarrow$) Suppose $x \in  a \cap b$. Since $x\in a\cap b \implies x\in c$ and $x \in a \cap b$, we have $x \in c$. Since $x \in a \cap b$, we have $x \in a$ and $x \in b$. Hence $x \in c$ and $x \in b$, i.e., $x \in b \cap c$. Thus $a \cap b \subseteq b \cap c$.

Similarly the other direction. So, if you show that $b \cap c \subseteq a \cap b$, then you can conclude $a \cap b = b \cap c$.

Comment: Clever! $x\in a\cap b  \implies x\in c$  gives $x\in b\cap c$. This means $a\cap b \subseteq b\cap c$

Comment: Similarly $x\in b\cap c \implies x \in a$ gives $x\in a\cap b$. This means $b\cap c \subseteq a\cap b$

Comment: @rsadhvika Nice, so you are understand it?

Comment: Yeah I get it. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to write it.  You have: $a \cap b \subseteq c$, and $b \cap c \subseteq a$.  So:
$$
    a \cap b \supseteq (b \cap c) \cap b = b \cap c
$$
and:
$$
    b \cap c \supseteq b \cap (a \cap b) = a \cap b
$$
So each set includes the other.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Hypothesis implies:}\ \, {\rm if}\ x\in b\,$ then $\,x\,\in\,\color{#c00} a\iff x\,\in\, \color{#0a0}c$

$\text{Therefore: }\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  x \in b\cap a\iff x\in b,\color{#c00}a\! \iff\! x\in b,\color{#0a0}c\iff x\in b\cap c$

Comment: Note how using *bidirectional* arrows allows us to do both directions at once.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need to show is if $A\cap B$ $\subseteq C$ and $B\cap C$ $\subseteq A$ then $A \cap B$ $=$ $B \cap C$

Can you see why this is true? Any element in $A\cap B$ is in C and B. Similarly, any element in $B \cap C$ is in A and in B as well.